# Аккордеон и теги dd

Tags: jquery, html

Решил сделать аккордеон и за основу взял ниспадающее меню:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#accordion dl#naz dd').hide();
$('#accordion dl#naz').hover(
    function(){
    $(this).find('dt').slideDown();
    },function(){
    $(this).find('dt').slideUp('fast');
    });
    });

</script>
<div id="accordion">
<dl>
    <dt>Один</dt>
    <dd>12345</dd>
    <dt>Два</dt>
    <dd>qwerrrtt</dd>
</dl>
</div>
```

Но ничего не работает. Может, это оттого, что эта конструкция не работает с `dd` и им подобным? И как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я реализовал вот так:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('dd').hide();
$('dt').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).next('dd').slideDown(300);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).next('dd').slideUp(1200);
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="accordion">
<dl id="naz">
    <dt>Один</dt>
    <dd>12345</dd>
    <dt>Два</dt>
    <dd>qwerrrtt</dd>
</dl>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Конечно, угловато. Надо чётко "ловить" элемент, чтобы эффект хорошо наблюдался. Для этого нужно более детально задать размеры элемента, чтобы сформировать область наведения, например. Появляющиеся элементы не должны "нарушать строй". Но всё же до ума уже Вам доводить :)) Надо поработать над `css`-свойствами элементов. Просто списки определений не совсем подходят для этих целей (у них особая раметка по умолчанию). Также я считаю, что функция `hover` для аккордеона - немного перебор - красиво, конечно, но всё же... при наведении на элемент проявляется другой элемент, при этом элемент, на который было произведено наведение изначально, может "уползти" из-под курсора и начнётся функция скрытия. Поэтому, на мой взгляд, делать аккордеоны по щелчку - нажал на определённый пункт и ждёшь, пока появится новый элемент.